# Rails select results into a plain old ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, activerecord

When selecting data from multiple tables and combining the results with union, can the result set be extracted directly into a plain old ruby object? Or would you need to fetch then loop through the results and then create each PORO directly, as done below?

```
sql = "SELECT id, title, author FROM books
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id,
              title + ' - ' + issue_number AS title,
              publisher AS author
       FROM magazines"

results = ApplicationRecord.connection.select_all(sql)

library = []

results.map do |reading_material|
  library << ReadingMaterial.new(reading_material.id, reading_material.title, reading_material.author)
end

class ReadingMaterial
  attr_reader :id, :title, :author

  def initialize(id, title, author)
    @id = id
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end
end
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you'll have to manually instantiate your POROs. You can refactor your code with ```library = results.map do |item|
  ReadingMaterial.new(item.id, item.title, item.author)
end```